# Sequences of probability distributions which do not converege uniformly and satisfy integral properites.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, uniform-convergence, economics

I'm looking for two (convergent) sequences of real-valued functions, $\{f_{k}\}$ and $\{g_{k}\}$, such that, for each $k$,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}f_{k}(t)dt\leq \int_{-\infty}^{x}g_{k}(t)dt$$
at every $x$, and such that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt> \int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)dt$$
for some $x$. Moreover, I would like $f_{k}, g_{k}, f,$ and $g$ to be probability distribution functions. That is, they are monotone with an upper bound of $1$ and a lower bound of $0$.

These conditions may be too restrictive for such functions to exist, but I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Edit: Moreover, I would like the distributions to be defined over a discrete space, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dynkin-system argument together with the given condition
$$\tag{1}\int_\infty^x f_k(t) dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^x g_k(t) dt$$
for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, one can already conclude that this integral inequality holds not only for sets of type $(-\infty,x]$, but for all Borel-measurable sets. As a consequence one finds that $f_k(x) \le g_k(x)$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

If we have convergence in some of the usual used forms (i.e. $L^p$-convergence, in probability or (almost-everywhere) pointwise), then we get that a subsequence convergences almost-everywhere. Taking the limits and noting that the union of countable many nullsets is again a nullset, we conclude that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Integrating (that is possible, if - for example - $f$ and $g$ are probablity densites) gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \ dt \le \int_{-\infty}^x g(t) \ dt$$
for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, as you have already suggested, the conditions are too restrictive.

If (1) should only hold for one fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then we first may note that the Fatou lemma implies that
$$\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^x f_n(t) dt \le \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-\infty}^x g_n(t) dt.$$
Thus, the requirements of the dominated convergence theorem have to be not fulfilled. For example take $f_n(x) = 1_{[0,1]}$ and $g_n = n 1_{(0,1/n]}$, then one has
$$\int_{-\infty}^1 f_k(t) dt \le \int_{-\infty}^1 g_k(t) dt$$
and $f_n \rightarrow 1_{[0,1]}$ and $g_n \rightarrow 0$ almost everywhere. Thus
$$0 \int_{-\infty}^1 g(t) dt < \int_{-\infty}^1 f(t) dt = 1.$$

Comment: I'm actually working on a problem where almost-everywhere doesn't cut it. I only need one x that fails the given condition.

Comment: If (1) holds for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then holds $\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt \leq \int_{-\infty}^x g(t) dt$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as well, as I have already underlined in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, how does $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g_{n}(t)dt$ imply that $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)dt\leq\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)dt$? Cant it be that $\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x}g_{n}(t)dt>\int_{-\infty}^{x}g(t)dt$ (it's been a while since I've taken measure theory)?

Comment: In general, it doesn't. This argument shows only that a counterexample cannot satisfies $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } \int_{-\infty}^x g_n(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^x g(t) dt$.